# Can I cook with fire?

Tags: cast-iron, stir-fry, fire

In Japanese restaurants, I always see the chefs doing crazy things with fire, and seeming to make very good grilled vegetables by lighting things on fire. I know most of that is for show, and that the volcano probably doesn't really cook the onions, but Can I light my frying pan on fire next time I'm making a stir fry and get well cooked vegetables?

Of course on the safety side, besides not being stupid with fire, are there other safety concerns I might not expect?

Comment: You can cook with fire, but making a fire inside your pan is about the stupidest way to do it. Or do you mean flambeing? This is a different thing and doesn't really cook the (bulk of the) food.

Comment: Too be honest I didnt know what that was. What's the "smartest" way to do it?

Comment: This is why it is stupid: http://media3.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/photo/gallery/091218/GAL-09Dec18-3382/media/PHO-09Dec18-194236.jpg If you see somebody "setting" food on fire, this is flambe. Else you can grill food using a fire made in a proper container, using a safe fuel. See the answers for more, sobachatina already wrote a good one.

Comment: Also, as you say you're a beginner, you may want to start with something easier. A fry pan over a burner is much easier to control...

Comment: Are you thinking of wok hei?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fire is typically a poor heat source for direct cooking. It fluctuates with every breeze so the heating is very erratic. It also produces a lot of soot which tastes terrible and is bad for you.

When cooking on a campfire much better results are had by cooking next to the coals than above the flame. Cooking with a gas flame is more reliable of course.

A couple direct cooking applications of fire in the kitchen, that I can think of are:

- Flambe: Lighting a sauce which contains a lot of alcohol to burn off some of the raw alcohol taste.
- Roasting: Putting a steaming basket over a gas flame and charring the skin of peppers or eggplant.
- Caramelizing: Using a blowtorch to put a crust on creme brulee or to sear the exterior of a sous vide steak.

I would recommend starting with the blowtorch for several reasons:

1. It is harder to burn your house down with a torch than with a pan of flame.
2. Blow torches are useful for things outside of the kitchen like stripping paint or starting the grill.
3. There is something deeply satisfying about wielding a hissing, blue, knife of fire that appeals to the caveman within.

As for safety. Keep a fire extinguisher on hand. Don't let kids or pets in the kitchen when you are playing with fire. Keep your home owner's insurance current.